# Adding waffle menu to html page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Is there a easy way to add the o365 waffle menu to a custom html outside o365 environment similar to how yammer embed can be added to any html?

Appreciate any quick response.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?